# How to give link to a file in subfolder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, partials

This is my page in View.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php $this->load->view('partials/page_head');?>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<div class="logo">Logo</div>
</header>
<?php $this->load->view('partials/menu');?>
<div id="content">
<?php $this->load->view('partials/', $subview); ?>
</div>
<footer>&copy; 2012 Codeigniter.tv</footer>
</div>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my menu page inside partials folder.

```
<menu>
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('example/listing'); ?>">Listing</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('example/detail'); ?>">Detail</a></li>
</ul>
</menu>
```

Below is the controller part.

```
<?php
class Example extends CI_Controller {
public $data = array('subview' => 'Oops, forgot to set a subview');
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('url');
}
public function listing() {
$this->data['subview'] = 'listing';
$this->load->view('layouts/layout', $this->data);
}
public function detail() {
$this->data['subview'] = 'detail';
$this->load->view('layouts/layout', $this->data);
}
}
```

I could not display the content in the file 'listing.php' which is in partials folder. When i run the project in localhost it saying not found. Can anyone help  me to correct my problems.

Comment: post controller part as well.

Comment: controller is added...

Comment: I given answer, have you checked it.

Answer (score 0):

modify views as bellow.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
      <?php $this->load->view('partials/page_head');?>
           <body>
       <div class="wrapper">
       <header>
        <div class="logo">Logo</div>
       </header>
    <?php $this->load->view('partials/menu');?>
        <div id="content">
      <?php $this->load->view('partials/'.$subview); ?>
    </div>
        <footer>&copy; 2012 Codeigniter.tv</footer>
      </div>
     <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')   </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your menu file as below

```html
<menu>
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('example'); ?>">Listing</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('example/detail'); ?>">Detail</a></li>
</ul>
</menu>
```

Comment: or you can use 
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('example/index'); ?>">Listing</a></li>